# Is there any way in Which I can execute file explorer to get a path to a certain folder?

Tags: java, windows

I am making a text editor but I can't find any way in which I can save the code like a modern IDE or notepad. Native windows notepad pops out a file-explorer to choose the path to save the file, can I make it in java?

Comment: You mean an "open"/"save" dialog?

Comment: i mean the file explorer that pops out when we save some thing in native windows notepad

Comment: @Coder: that's the file chooser dialog.

Answer (score 0):

Don't know which technology you're using for the GUI but the Swing JFileChooser is just what you are looking for:

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/filechooser.html

Comment: Thanks,That was what I was looking for